# Group by two column with min condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have next table:

```
| ID |ID2  | price|
+----+---+----+
| A  | AA   | 7 |
| B  | AA   | 3 |
| C  | AA   | 4 |
| D  | BB   | 7 |
| I  | BB   | 2 |
| F  | BB   | 3 |
| G  | CC   | 9 |
| E  | CC   | 4 |
| K  | CC   | 1 |

+----+---+---+
```

And I need to get the next table
group by ID2 with min field price and corresponding min price field ID1

```
| ID1 | ID2 | min_price |
+----+---+---+----------
| B  | AA   | 3         |
| I  | BB   | 2         |
| K  | CC   | 1         |
+----+---+---+---------
```

Comment: why `B  | AA   | 1    `  and `I  | BB   | 9`? there is no such records in source table

Answer (score 1):

```
select a.id, a.id2, a.price from #yourtable a
 join 
    (
    select  id2, min(price) AS price 
    from #yourtable
    group by id2 
    )b 
 on a.id2=b.id2 and a.price=b.price
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM
    #table t
    INNER JOIN (
       SELECT
          ID2
          ,MIN(price) as min_price
       FROM
          #table
       GROUP BY
          ID2
    ) g
    ON t.ID2 = g.ID2
    AND t.price = g.min_price
```

Step 1 find the minimum price, step 2 relate back to get the original record that matches to get the ID.  There are other ways to do this as well.

Note that if your dataset contains 2 records in the same ID2 with the same price then more than 1 record will always be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your explanation, we need to group by id2 and get the lowest price and its corresponding id.
Here is the query for the same

```
SELECT id,
  id2,
  price
FROM NEXT
WHERE (price,id2) IN
  (SELECT MIN(price), id2 FROM NEXT GROUP BY id2
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/295702/2

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t1 t2
ON t1.id2=t2.id2
  AND t1.price>t2.price
WHERE t2.ID IS NULL
```